# userDefaults and comparing arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got problem with saving and comparing data. First I download data and save my data (array,dict)to userDefaults. After redownloading I need to compare if my new array have some new data which I haven't saved in userDefaults. So its mean I should find the data that is not the same inside my old data and add them to my new array.

```
    NSMutableDictionary* tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    NSMutableDictionary* copyDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];


    NSMutableArray *dataGroupsArr = [NSMutableArray new];


    NSMutableDictionary *dataGroupsDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    dataGroupsDict[@"name"] = @"FirstGroup"; // I dont need groups at the moment

    NSMutableArray *datas = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

FOR ........ (parser)

```
 {            
 NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

 data[@"dataID"] = [@"some data from parser"];

 [datas addObject:data];
 }];

    dataGroupsDict[@"datas"] = datas;
   [dataGroupsArr addObject:dataGroupsDict];
   tmpDict[@"dataGroups"] = dataGroupsArr;
```

After I save data Im trying to load them from userdefualts

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    copyDict = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"dataDownloadArr"];

    //data never added
    if(copyDict == nil){
        [userDefaults setObject:tmpDict forKey:@"dataDownloadArr"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i< [copyDict[@"dataGroups"][0][@"datas"]count]; i++){
            NSLog(@"%@", copyDict[@"dataGroups"][0][@"datas"][i][@"dataID"]);

        }

    }
```

Now I don't know how to compare data, and if there is new data in my new array how to add it to old one.

Comment: Is it for iOS or macOS? Please specify in tags

Comment: @VadimKotov Does it matter?

Comment: Could you just overwrite the old with the new one? That'd make things easier. If the dict can't change, overwriting it would automatically add the new changes and given that the old one hasn't changed, the old values would stay the same.

Comment: @Willeke I don't really know. Usually it matters. Maybe it can help someone to get the context of the question

Comment: From Apple's documentation…  `synchronize()` _"… this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use NSData instance method isEqualToData?

> Two data objects are equal if they hold the same number of bytes, and
>   if the bytes at the same position in the objects are the same.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1409330-isequaltodata

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue what I did is I asked the backend developer to send a value as modified_date and create a dictionary containing dataArray and modified_date. So after re-downloading you can just check for modified_date and replace the dataArray instead of comparing every array element.